# Understanding a the solution of the apmo problem.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, contest-math

Prove that the equation $[ 6(6a^2 + 3b^2 + c^2) = 5n^2  ]$ has no solutions in integers except $a = b = c = n = 0$

> The left side is divisible by 3, so 3 must divide n. So $5n^{2}-36a^{2}-18b^{2}$ is divisible by 9, so 3 must divide c. We can now divide out the factor 9 to get: $4a^{2}+2b^{2}+6d^{2}=5m^{2}$. Now take  a, b, d, m to be the solution with the smallest m, and consider residues mod 16. Squares = 0, 1, 4, or 9 mod 16. Clearly m is even so $5m^{2}$ = 0 or 4 mod 16. Similarly, $4a^{2}$ = 0 or 4 mod 16. Hence $2b^{2}+6d^{2}$ = 0, 4 or 12 mod 16. But $2b^{2}$ = 0, 2 or 8 mod 16 and $6d^{2}$ = 0, 6 or 8 mod 16. Hence $2b^{2}+6d^{2}$ = 0, 2, 6, 8, 10 or 14 mod 16. So it must be 0. So b and d are both even. So a cannot be even, otherwise m/2, a/2, b/2, d/2 would be a solution with smaller m/2 < m.

So we can divide out the factor 4 and get: $a^{2}+2e^{2}+6f^{2}=5k^{2}$ with $a$ odd. Hence k is also odd. So $5k^{2}-a^{2}$ = 4 or 12 mod 16. But we have just seen that $2e^{2}+6 f^{2}$ cannot be 4 or 12 mod 16. So there are no solutions

This is a problem for. The APMO maths contest 1989 ,. The solution is provided but I fail to understand the modulo 16 part of the answer. Why modulo 16 is considered in this problem?

Comment: We can consider an equation in integers modulo $n$ for any positive integer $n$. Why is this a problem for you? Often $n=2$, or $n=4$ for squares. Here $16=4^2$ is natural.

Comment: How are we getting $2b^2+6d^2$=0,4,12 mod 16, I am unable to get the idea.

Comment: your quadratic form $36a^2+18 b^2 + 6 c^2 - 5 n^2$ is isotropic over the reals as it is indefinite.  The remaining things to check are modulo prime powers   for $2,3,5.$  For the prime $2$  there is a sort of delay because odd squares are $1 \pmod 8$   Anyway, worth seeing with a simple computer program,  let $a,b,c,d$ go from $0 to 7$   and then caefully reduce the outcome $\pmod 8.$   From your comments, I imagine there are solutions with some odd variables. Then, same experiment for $\pmod {16}$ which likely succeeds, as  all must be even, I expect, for the form to be $0 \pmod {16}$

Comment: It's the classic Fermat's Infinite Descent, so read up on the technique if you're unfamiliar with it. $\quad$ If you're asking why we use modulo 16 instead of say 15 or 17, then that come with experience / understanding what to look out for. (IE The goal is to prove that the terms share a common factor, like we did in the first part of taking modulo 3)